# ¿Como cambiar la fecha de un commit antes de hacer 'git push'?

Tags: git

Estuve adelantando trabajo pues necesito tiempo libre los próximos días y ya he comiteado los cambios a mi repositorio local y pusheado un fork que tengo como backup.

Ahora, en cuanto al origen, quiero pushear los commits A y B con fecha de digamos el próximo lunes (no quiero que tengan la fecha original del commit).

Igual pasa con los commits C y D, que quiero pushear el día martes, con fecha del martes.

<strike>¿Es posible hacer esto usando git sin hacer un `git reset ...` y volviendo a comitear el lunes y martes respectivamente?</strike>

Entiendo que hay dos partes en esto, una seria cambiar la fecha del commit y la otra seria pushear solo un grupo de commits el lunes y otro el martes.

### Actualización:

No puedo hacer un `git reset` y volver a comitear usando `git commit --date` pues estos commits modifican los mismos archivos y no seria consistente, la próxima vez lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: probaste con git commit --date , eso sobre escribe la fecha del commit , según la documentación oficial

Comment: Gracias @Santi92, me sirve la información pero no para esta vez.

Comment: Bueno esto rompe de alguna forma con el proposito de versionamiento, lo que haría yo es cambiar la fecha del servidor, y asegurar que este no este sincronizado con la red, de esa forma se registraran los commits con la fecha/hora que yo decida. :)

Comment: @Elenasys me temo que la hora del commit ya esta establecida y cambiar la hora del servidor cambiara la hora del push, no del commit. De cualquier modo, no puedo hacerlo, es un servidor externo.

Comment: ok, es um servidor externo, seria interesante saber una repuesta a esto,;saludos.

Answer (score 4):

> (no quiero que tengan la fecha original del commit)

Me parece que hay un error de concepto aquí. Cuando "pusheas" no estás "enviando al repositorio", simplemente estás sincronizando (tal vez parcialmente) el repositorio remoto con el local. GIT (a diferencia de CVS o Subversion) es distribuido, lo cual significa que en realidad existe un solo repositorio, que está espejado (tal vez parcialmente) en distintos lugares. Por lo tanto, simplemente no puedes pushear un commit con datos diferentes (en este caso la fecha). El repositorio es el mismo, el commit es el mismo.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es cambiar la fecha del commit (local), y luego pushearlo:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "6489982f81797b71534357fa5a442a2604c61eff" ]
         then
                  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2016-03-20T05:57:12-03:00"
                  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2016-03-20T05:57:12-03:00"
     fi'
```

(copiado de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/454750/277304) (cambia el commit hash y la fecha-hora)

Con respecto a pushear solo algunos commits, la sintaxis es:

```
   git push <remoto> <SHA del commit>:<branch>
```